# Did any army try speed volley fire by passing pre-loaded muskets to the front line?

Tags: military, war, battle, gun-politics

Early 16th to 18th century muskets had 2 big disadvantages. Musketeers needed minimum 20-30 seconds to reload them and they were very inaccurate, because projectile (usually small lead ball) was much smaller than barrel of the musket. They were designed this way on purpose, because after each firing, small residues of black powder settled on the barrel walls and if projectile would perfectly fit the barrel, the musket choked with black powder couldn't be used for more than 4 firings.

Did any army ever try to came to open field battle with multiple already loaded muskets (let say at least 4) which were passed by solders in second line to solders in front line for quick volley fire ? Solders in front line would fire first volley when enemy was less than 70 meters from them, pass used musket to solders in second line and then take new already loaded musket so they can quickly fire at least 3 other volleys before enemy can close the distance between them.

Once the enemy get to close they would simply take their own musket with bayonet from their back (or draw their own sword) to defend their front line from enemy attack, while second line solders would backtrack behind other 3 or 4 lines to have time to reload all their 4 used muskets. At the end of battle formation could also wait other solders, who help them with reloading of those 4 muskets and then use them for other firings.

4 muskets that were used for quick volley fire during beginning of the battle could use bigger projectiles (which perfectly fit the barrel) which would make them more accurate even for distance of 70 meters. Then those muskets can be reload with smaller projectiles or be refired at least 3 times with original projectiles before they must be cleaned from black powder.

Solders in front line (and any other line except second one) would use smaller projectiles for muskets with bayonets, which can be refired dozens times and still be accurate at point-blank range.

Did any army in 15th to 18th century fight this way ? I heard that Dutch army used 6 lines, which simple jumped in front each other for quick volley fire, but this seems like better solution.

In summary, passing multiple already loaded muskets could be great solution for long reloading times and using muskets with projectiles that perfectly fit the barrel for quick opening volley fire was good solution to accuracy problem.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128259/discussion-on-question-by-crossbow10-did-any-army-try-speed-volley-fire-by-passi).